# tile name is not display only object name is display on Django admin

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Blog(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
auther=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
body=models.TextField(default="")

def __self__(self):
    return self.title
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

BLOG
Blog object (3)
Blog object (2)
Blog object (1)

Here title name is not shown

Answer (score 1):

```
def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Comment: Please give me other idea

Comment: @Dhiraj have you tried replacing the __self__ method with the __str__ method like above yet? the answer is corrected following the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#str). Please check your model again